# Python - Printing to GUI instead of terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Very new to Python here, and I'm trying to create a GUI app that returns a random recipe. Currently the print happens at the terminal, and I'd like it to print in the GUI instead.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import random



root = tk.Tk()

def printRecipes():
    recipes = [
        "Tom Yum Soup",

        "Carnitas",

        "General Tso's Chicken"
    ]
    print(random.choice(recipes))


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=700, bg="#A8D1BB")
canvas.pack()

magic = tk.Button(root, text="Print", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="black", command=printRecipes)
magic.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This doesn't work, as most of you already know. I've read that I need to use a label or text for it, but the example I've found all involved static print statements like

```
label = Label(root,text="Recipe")
    label.pack
```

Comment: You can instead of `print` then use `label.config(text='what had to be printed')` or use a StringVar, but this is probably the easiest

Comment: Also you never actually call `.pack()` on the label. Change `label.pack` to `label.pack()`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? I need it to be dynamic, and not supply just a pre-determined text. I don't quite understand how this implementation would provide randomized output from my "recipes" list

Answer (score 1):

To "print" a value to a GUI Window, a `Label` is used. `.config()` is a useful function. It is used to configure the provided widget.

Below `magic.pack()`, add this code. Notice that there is no `text` parameter. We will use that later.

```
label1=Label(root,pady=10,font=("arial",15))
label1.pack()
```

Next, in the function, where you had `print(random.choice(recipes))`, we will add:

```
label1.config(text=random.choice(recipes))
```

Notice that we used `.config()` and the `text` parameter. We configured the label, and added some text to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `tk.StringVar` for this, i.e. a variable which you can change and the label can read from:

```
label_str = tk.StringVar(value="Some text")
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_str)
```

Then, to update the value of this label and show it on the GUI:

```
label_str.set("New text")
label.update()
```

Comment: it is not necessary to use StringVar tho, and You don't need to use `label.update()`

Comment: @matiiss The `.update()` call is sometimes necessary, especially if you want to see the update as soon as possible. The `StringVar` instead of `.config` is just good practice.

Comment: In this case `.update()` is probably not too bad, but I have read that in general it isn't too good of a practice since it can cause some issues, but `StringVar` and `.config()` are equally good practices except StringVar has some tracer or sth I don't know and `.config()` makes shorter code

Comment: yes, the `trace` function on StringVar is called when the value of the string changes, so it is quite useful to validate user inputs and even to implement a search bar :)

Comment: Thanks, The StringVar works, however I don't think this covers the scope I need. I need it to return a randomized entry from my list of recipes, and from my understanding, this will update the entry with a predefined string

Comment: well yes..but you can extract the "predefined string" randomly from you list..